# Separate the data in MySQL using comma and period

Tags: mysql

I have a database here

```
select * from sample

id   | desc
-----+--------------------------------------
1    | blue , big , 100.00 . red, small, 200
```

I want to make it like this

```
id    | color | size | price
------+-------+------+-------
1     | blue  |big   | 100.00
1     | red   |small | 200.00
```

Is there any body knows how can i query that ? I am using MySQL . 
Thanks for the reply .

Comment: what you want is better done using some programming language, your table is poorly done and needs urgent normalization.

Comment: Completely agree with Prix. Further, if you can't change your database schema, you should at least settle on one separator character. It will be tedious to differentiate the period separating your price and colour "fields" from a decimal point in the price.

Comment: Sounds to me like student is actually trying to change their database structure, and needs a way to migrate the data.